# Django: How to get selected text of DropDown in Template?

Tags: django

In the template I get the whole DropDown correctly shown with something like this:

```
{{form.deal_type}}
```

But what if I wanted just the text of the selected dropdown shown?

This shows me just a foreignkey.

```
{{form.deal_type.value}}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why you want to do this exactly, but try this.

#### TO LOOP:

```
{% for value, text in form.deal_type.field.choices %}
    {{ value }}: {{ text }}
    {% if value == form.deal_type.value %}
        <strong>{{ text }}</strong> <!-- THIS IS THE SELECTED ONE... -->
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

#### EDIT:

I meant the above code as an illustration, not that you should use it verbatim. This code will do more like what you want.

```
{{ form.deal_type.label_tag }}
{% for value, text in form.deal_type.field.choices %}
    {% if value == form.deal_type.value %}
        {{ text }}
        <input type="hidden" name="deal_type" value="{{ value }}" />
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Well, in fact I don't want to allow them to change the value in my case. Hence I thought a string would be best.  I recon I could have also disabled it instead...

Comment: btw this seems promising, but it gives: `: --------- 1: deal 2 deal 2 2: deal 1 `, instead of one value.

Comment: see my edit, I didn't intend my first snippet to be usable code, I wanted to illustrate a method of getting text out of the  choice field. The hidden field makes it so that the value gets submitted with the rest of the form.

Comment: Ahh now I understand why it behaved like this.  The `{{ value }}: {{ text }}` kind of messed up the loop. now it works. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  To solve it I just passed the value to the template directly from the view. So in your view you presumably have something in the way of

```
data = {'form' :form,}    
return render_to_response('destination.html', data, context_instance = RequestContext)
```

In data you are passing the form that includes deal_type.  Add to 
data a variable deal_type set equal to Object.deal_type.display_value with

```
data = {'form' :form,} 
if Object.deal_type: data['deal_type'] = Object.deal_type.display_value   
return render_to_response('destination.html', data, context_instance = RequestContext)
```

Then on your template you can just use

```
{% if condition_to_show_just_text %}
    {{deal_type}} {{form.deal_type.as_hidden}}
{% else %}
    {{form.deal_type}}
{% endif %}
```

It may be insiginificant in this case, but it seemed to me that if the list was long, iterating with the for loop on the template would be less efficient than pulling directly from the object